# Is there a way to overlap the image over the svg file?

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I want to move my image thats in .png format on top of the SVG file i have loaded , Any help on how to do that

```
var s = Snap();
Snap.load('tshirt.svg'.function(f){
               var g = f.select('g');
               g.select('#path3128').attr({fill:'yellow'};
               s.append(g);
               });

var image = s.image("graphic.png", 0, 0, 200, 200);
image.drag();
```

i want that i should be able to drag the *graphic.png* on top of *tshirt.svg* , it should not be hidden by the tshirt.svg

Comment: You need to add the png after the svg. The problem is as the Snap.load is async, it will probably append it after. So you can either add the png load as part of the Snap.load callback, or add a group elements before either load, and append them to the group elements (as the group elements will retain their order).

Comment: Thanks it worked , i just had to append the image  

s.append(image);